# Suggestion for makefile structure for multiple firmware images and lots of conditional compilation

Tags: c, makefile, firmware

I'm looking for suggestions on makefile organization.  I am not a makefile expert.  I don't mind learning, but it's not currently a strength of mine.

The problem:
I have inherited a project that builds multiple firmware images for multiple similar but different platforms.  In general, they share a common processor but use different peripherals or configure peripherals differently (at compile time) such that just building a library of common code isn't enough.

The current solution feels a bit lacking.  It is a giant folder with all of the code grouped together.  There exists a specific Makefile for each platform in this form: Makefile.XXX.mak.  These makefiles include a common makefile (Makefile.common.mak) that does things like define the TOOLCHAIN_PATH and INDLUDE_PATH and things like that.  The specific makefiles each enumerate all of the .c/.cpp files that are needed for the specific firmware image as well as all of the defines that are used within those files.

I'd like to do something that includes building a library (or a few libraries) with the common files, but it seems like that library would need to be forced to rebuild for each firmware image, due to different defines each image requires.  I'd also like to reduce the number of makefiles out there and perhaps use targets rather than unique makefiles.  Each firmware image requires a call 'make -f Makefile.XXX.mak' to build.

Comment: Good question but not really suitable to the SO format as it is quite broad and will lead to a lot of opinion-based answers.

Comment: You could do a search-engine query on the autotools there are some tutorials on how to autoconfiscate a project. It's also a bit complicated but in the end it is much easier than writing your own configure and Makefile scripts. see eg http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/books/autotools_a_guide_to_autoconf_automake_libtool

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  Yes, I felt hesitant to post this one as it is somewhat broad and asks for opinions.

Comment: @hetepeperfan - Did you mean to write autoconfiscate or autoconfigure?

Comment: @RichvonLehe autoconfiscate is a special term that means make a project ready for the autotools. In the end the autotools will make your configure file and makefile and optionally build shared libraries, but the link I mentionned can tell you a lot more.

Comment: BTW - not sure if you were admins, but I would understand if this question gets closed due to scope.

Comment: Do the different images have different names? Do you have a good test harness?

Comment: Yes, the different images have different names and are stored in unique build folders.  Not sure yet about the test harness.  I haven't looked much beyond this current task.